# xaml won't see external library classes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

I'm following [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/hh563947.aspx) from Microsoft to use a Portable Class Library in a Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT Project. At the end they show an example in WPF.
It works well with WPF, you can use a class from the external library in the xaml for example to set the d:DataContext property of the window.
However with Windows Phone app, after adding the namespace alias in xaml, intellisense won't find the classes, and compiler insults me.
I found a workaround by creating dummy classes in the app project namespace, like this:

```
namespace App
{
    public class dummyClass : externalLibrary.externalClass
    {}
}
```

Using this, intellisense works.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Intellisense in xaml often sucks.  I don't rely on it anymore :/

Comment: Well, it got a lot better with VS2013 I think. But little things like this are getting annoying for sure!